# How to list travel history in the UK?

Tags: visas, uk

I am a 21 year old from Canada applying for a Tier 5 Youth Mobility Visa.

This is my travel history in the UK:

**1: October 20th 2017 - Mid January 2018**

2: Approx **January 29th 2018 - January 31st 2018** (was in UK for around 2-3 days just catching a flight from London to Norway

3: **March 15th - April 31st 2018**

On my application it asks for my two most recent trips to the UK. I can ONLY list two maximum. I cannot list all three.

Should I not include my transit trip as it was so minor?

Basically should I list my March and January trips?

Or should I list my March and October trips?

I don't want to seem like I'm hiding my October history. But I want to do what's best.

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A three day trip was not a transit trip. To you it appears so, to UK immigration it is not. UK specifically **limits transit to 48 hours**

[Visitor in Transit visa](https://www.gov.uk/transit-visa/visitor-in-transit-visa)

> You might need a Visitor in Transit visa if you’re from outside the
>   European Economic Area (EEA) and Switzerland and you’ll:
>
> - be changing flights in the UK on your way to another country
> - go through immigration control, for example to check in your luggage    for a connecting flight
> - leave the UK **within 48 hours**
> - not work or study while in the UK

List the last two.